# Teach a multiclass CNN classifier on images with highlighted target

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I'm building a classifier for objects located in images. There are really good networks for semantic segmentation, like "segment-anything", and I wonder is it possible to teach a CNN, i.e., ResNet, on images produced by multiplication of the original image and each of the binary masks created by Segment-Anything net?

The flow I'm interested is:

1. Segment them with some segmentation network, like "segment-anything".
2. Multiply the original image with each of the binary masks to get only the segmented object in the image, and the background as '0', as shown in the following image [image].
3. Select images of the desired targets, and place them in folders with different labels, e.g., 1, 2, 3, etc, and all the non-targets in folder with label '0'.

My intuition tells me that due to the fact that most of the image is '0', there will be a problem with gradients in the process of training, but I wanted to know:

1. Is this approach possible, or maybe theres some other way I should organize the images
2. What the go-to solution for this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance,
Michael